# Collecting types that implement a particular interface without casting?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Basically I wanna know if all the types in a particular namespace implements a particular interface like `IEnumerable`.

I know I can do:

```
foreach type ...
    if type is IEnumerable
        ...
```

But I don't wanna cast the type just to query if it implements an interface, because the cast will be thrown away either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the **is** operator is not a cast, it is a test, which sounds like what you want. Type casting in C# is done either using the forced casting operator (name?) like so:

```
((IEnumerable)someCollection)
```

or the safe casting operator:

```
someCollection as IEnumerable
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure is isn't casting? I thought it was, because is isn't recommended if you want to use the cast, so AS is better instead of IS first AS after because of double casting AFAIK.

Comment: Actually it's not recommended because "as" first does an "is" check, then performs the cast. So, if you do "is" then "as", you're checking the type twice (effectively doing "is", then "is" again followed by a cast).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I've read you correctly, you want a list of types in an enumeration that implement an particular interface or supertype. Perhaps [Enumerable.OfType(this IEnumerable source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) is useful?

```
var enumerables = myListOfThingsToCheck.OfType<IEnumerable>();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. OfType doesn't care about whether the list is type unsafe? Also is there a version of this to be used on single types outside a collection?

Comment: No list is necessarily "type unsafe" unless it's in an unsafe code block. It might happen to be a list of "System.Object", however, which is exactly what this method was designed for. If you're looking to do this on a single object, just use "is".

Comment: Thanks lc. Btw by type safe I meant storing same types vs different types on a list, if it looked different.

Comment: Bear in mind, under the covers, OfType is using the "is" operator to do its thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work also if you'd rather use lambda syntax.

```
var enumerables=Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace == "YOUR NAMESPACE HERE").OfType<IEnumerable>();
```